Debugging failing OGR /vsicurl call
I'm trying to open a remote GeoJSON source which requires an API key to be set in the request header. I have got it to work in Python 2 as follows:
import requests

headers = {'ApiKey': 'MY_API_KEY'}
response = requests.get('https://www.example.com/geojson-endpoint', headers=headers)
if response.status_code == 200:
    print(response.text.encode("utf-8"))

I'm hoping to get this to work without Python:
"C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.20.3\bin\ogrinfo" --debug ON --config CPL_CURL_VERBOSE YES -ro -al -so "GEOJSON:/vsicurl?header_file=d%3A%2Fapikey.headers&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2Fgeojson-endpoint"

d:\apikey.headers contains:
ApiKey:MY_API_KEY

This fails, but I don't know enough to understand where the issue is:
GDAL: Auto register C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.20.3\bin\gdalplugins\gdal_ECW_JP2ECW.dll using GDALRegister_ECW_JP2ECW.
GDAL: Auto register C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.20.3\bin\gdalplugins\gdal_GEOR.dll using GDALRegister_GEOR.
GDAL: Auto register C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.20.3\bin\gdalplugins\gdal_HDF5.dll using GDALRegister_HDF5.
GDAL: Auto register C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.20.3\bin\gdalplugins\gdal_MG4Lidar.dll using GDALRegister_MG4Lidar.
GDAL: Auto register C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.20.3\bin\gdalplugins\gdal_MrSID.dll using GDALRegister_MrSID.
GDAL: Auto register C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.20.3\bin\gdalplugins\ogr_OCI.dll using RegisterOGROCI.
GDAL: Auto register C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.20.3\bin\gdalplugins\ogr_SOSI.dll using RegisterOGRSOSI.
HTTP: libcurl/7.75.0 OpenSSL/1.1.1h zlib/1.2.11 WinIDN
* Couldn't find host www.example.com in the .netrc file; using defaults
*   Trying [endpoint IP address]:443...
* Connected to www.example.com ([endpoint IP address]) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*  CAfile: D:\MapServer\shared\certs\curl-ca-bundle.crt
*  CApath: none
* SSL connection using TLSv1.3 / TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
* ALPN, server accepted to use http/1.1
* Server certificate:
*  subject: CN=www.example.com
*  start date: Oct 21 17:06:49 2024 GMT
*  expire date: Jan 19 17:06:48 2025 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "www.example.com" matched cert's "*.example.com"
*  issuer: C=US; O=Google Trust Services; CN=WE1
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
> HEAD /geojson-endpoint HTTP/1.1
Host: www.example.com
Accept: */*
ApiKey:[MY_API_KEY]
* old SSL session ID is stale, removing
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed
< Date: Wed, 11 Dec 2024 08:35:59 GMT
< Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
< Content-Length: 73
< Connection: keep-alive
< Cache-Control: no-cache
< pragma: no-cache
< allow: GET
< expires: -1
< x-aspnet-version: 4.0.30319
< x-powered-by: ASP.NET
< CF-Cache-Status: DYNAMIC
< Report-To: {"endpoints":[{"url":"https:\/\/a.nel.cloudflare.com\/report\/v4?s=[SOME_LONG_GUID]"}],"group":"cf-nel","max_age":604800}
< NEL: {"success_fraction":0,"report_to":"cf-nel","max_age":604800}
< Server: cloudflare
< CF-RAY: 8f0424fb0c17beba-LHR
< server-timing: cfL4;desc="?proto=TCP&rtt=1686&min_rtt=1683&rtt_var=633&sent=4&recv=6&lost=0&retrans=0&sent_bytes=2862&recv_bytes=767&delivery_rate=1734997&cwnd=251&unsent_bytes=0&cid=4e73b91f9e9c289b&ts=61&x=0"
<
* Connection #0 to host www.example.com left intact
VSICURL: HEAD not allowed. Retrying with GET
* Couldn't find host www.example.com in the .netrc file; using defaults
* Found bundle for host www.example.com: 0x240caeadc30 [serially]
* Re-using existing connection! (#0) with host www.example.com
* Connected to www.example.com ([endpoint IP address]) port 443 (#0)
> GET /geojson-endpoint HTTP/1.1
Host: www.example.com
Accept: */*
ApiKey:[MY_API_KEY]

* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Wed, 11 Dec 2024 08:36:00 GMT
< Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
< Content-Length: 321298
< Connection: keep-alive
< Cache-Control: no-cache
< pragma: no-cache
< expires: -1
< x-aspnet-version: 4.0.30319
< x-powered-by: ASP.NET
< CF-Cache-Status: DYNAMIC
< Report-To: {"endpoints":[{"url":"https:\/\/a.nel.cloudflare.com\/report\/v4?s=[LONG_GUID]]"}],"group":"cf-nel","max_age":604800}
< NEL: {"success_fraction":0,"report_to":"cf-nel","max_age":604800}
< Server: cloudflare
< CF-RAY: 8f0424fb7c81beba-LHR
< server-timing: cfL4;desc="?proto=TCP&rtt=4634&min_rtt=1683&rtt_var=6372&sent=6&recv=7&lost=0&retrans=0&sent_bytes=4282&recv_bytes=936&delivery_rate=1734997&cwnd=252&unsent_bytes=0&cid=4e73b91f9e9c289b&ts=237&x=0"
* Failed writing header
* Closing connection 0
VSICURL: GetFileSize(https://www.example.com/geojson-endpoint)=321298  response_code=200
FAILURE:
Unable to open datasource `GEOJSON:/vsicurl?header_file=d%3A%2Fapikey.headers&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2Fgeojson-endpoint' with the following drivers.
  -> JP2ECW
  -> BAG
  -> OCI
  -> SOSI
  -> ESRIC
  -> PCIDSK
  -> netCDF
  -> PDS4
  -> VICAR
  -> JP2OpenJPEG
  -> PDF
  -> MBTiles
  -> EEDA
  -> OGCAPI
  -> DB2ODBC
  -> ESRI Shapefile
  -> MapInfo File
  -> UK .NTF
  -> LVBAG
  -> OGR_SDTS
  -> S57
  -> DGN
  -> OGR_VRT
  -> REC
  -> Memory
  -> CSV
  -> NAS
  -> GML
  -> GPX
  -> LIBKML
  -> KML
  -> GeoJSON
  -> GeoJSONSeq
  -> ESRIJSON
  -> TopoJSON
  -> Interlis 1
  -> Interlis 2
  -> OGR_GMT
  -> GPKG
  -> SQLite
  -> ODBC
  -> WAsP
  -> PGeo
  -> MSSQLSpatial
  -> OGR_OGDI
  -> PostgreSQL
  -> MySQL
  -> OpenFileGDB
  -> DXF
  -> CAD
  -> FlatGeobuf
  -> Geoconcept
  -> GeoRSS
  -> GPSTrackMaker
  -> VFK
  -> PGDUMP
  -> OSM
  -> GPSBabel
  -> OGR_PDS
  -> WFS
  -> OAPIF
  -> Geomedia
  -> EDIGEO
  -> SVG
  -> CouchDB
  -> Cloudant
  -> Idrisi
  -> ARCGEN
  -> XLS
  -> ODS
  -> XLSX
  -> Elasticsearch
  -> Walk
  -> Carto
  -> AmigoCloud
  -> SXF
  -> Selafin
  -> JML
  -> PLSCENES
  -> CSW
  -> VDV
  -> GMLAS
  -> MVT
  -> NGW
  -> MapML
  -> TIGER
  -> AVCBin
  -> AVCE00
  -> HTTP
GDAL: In GDALDestroy - unloading GDAL shared library.

How do I determine where the issue lies? Is ogr with vsicurl failing to work with Cloudfront, perhaps? That's just a guess, based on some searching, but when that has been an issue, I thought it was because the remote file size wasn't available. The logs suggest that's not the case here, though:
VSICURL: GetFileSize(https://www.example.com/geojson-endpoint)=321298  response_code=200

Any ideas?

If I use the Python script to download the GeoJSON, ogrinfo reads the local copy fine:
D:\>"C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.20.3\bin\ogrinfo" --debug ON --config CPL_CURL_VERBOSE YES -ro -al -so ./downloaded.json
GDAL: Auto register C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.20.3\bin\gdalplugins\gdal_ECW_JP2ECW.dll using GDALRegister_ECW_JP2ECW.
GDAL: Auto register C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.20.3\bin\gdalplugins\gdal_GEOR.dll using GDALRegister_GEOR.
GDAL: Auto register C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.20.3\bin\gdalplugins\gdal_HDF5.dll using GDALRegister_HDF5.
GDAL: Auto register C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.20.3\bin\gdalplugins\gdal_MG4Lidar.dll using GDALRegister_MG4Lidar.
GDAL: Auto register C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.20.3\bin\gdalplugins\gdal_MrSID.dll using GDALRegister_MrSID.
GDAL: Auto register C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.20.3\bin\gdalplugins\ogr_OCI.dll using RegisterOGROCI.
GDAL: Auto register C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.20.3\bin\gdalplugins\ogr_SOSI.dll using RegisterOGRSOSI.
GeoJSON: First pass: 100.00 %
GDAL: GDALOpen(./downloaded.json, this=000001AD1B1819E0) succeeds as GeoJSON.
INFO: Open of `./downloaded.json'
      using driver `GeoJSON' successful.
OGR: GetLayerCount() = 1


Layer name: Layer1
Geometry: Point
Feature Count: 399
Extent: (0.000000, 0.000000) - (360447.000000, 403825.000000)
Layer SRS WKT:
GEOGCRS["WGS 84",
    DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984",
        ELLIPSOID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
        ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    CS[ellipsoidal,2],
        AXIS["geodetic latitude (Lat)",north,
            ORDER[1],
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
        AXIS["geodetic longitude (Lon)",east,
            ORDER[2],
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    ID["EPSG",4326]]
Data axis to CRS axis mapping: 2,1
StructureID: Integer (0.0)
Authority: String (0.0)
Name: String (0.0)
Identifier: String (0.0)
StructureType: String (0.0)
Length: Real (0.0)
YearOfConstruction: Integer (0.0)
Description: String (0.0)
Comments: String (0.0)
IsHighwayStructure: Integer(Boolean) (1.0)
OnInspectionProgramme: String (0.0)
Owner: String (0.0)
MaintainingAuthority: String (0.0)
ObstacleCrossedList: String (0.0)
ObstacleCarriedList: String (0.0)
HALoading: String (0.0)
Archived: Integer(Boolean) (1.0)
Restriction: String (0.0)
District: String (0.0)
BCIAVG: Real (0.0)
BCICRT: Real (0.0)
BCSAVG: Real (0.0)
BCSCRT: Real (0.0)
StateOfGoodRepair: Real (0.0)
BCIRating: String (0.0)
LatestPI: DateTime (0.0)
LatestGI: DateTime (0.0)
Geometry: String (0.0)
AssessmentNotRequired: Integer (0.0)
GDAL: GDALClose(./downloaded.json, this=000001AD1B1819E0)
GDAL: In GDALDestroy - unloading GDAL shared library.

For info:
D:\>"C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.20.3\bin\ogrinfo" --version
GDAL 3.3.1, released 2021/06/28


Have you tried the alternative method with a configuration option --config GDAL_HTTP_HEADER_FILE d:/apikay.headers? I used intentionally forward slash, it should work also on Windows. Backward slash is often used as an escape character and may need double escaping.

@user30184 Thank you - that worked better, but perhaps exposed the underlying insoluble issue: ERROR 1: Range downloading not supported by this server!. I guess this could be Cloudfront not being compatible.

Please write what you have learned as an answer.

On the suggestion of @user30184, I switched to this syntax:
"C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.20.3\bin\ogrinfo" --config GDAL_HTTP_HEADER_FILE d:/apikay.headers --debug ON --config CPL_CURL_VERBOSE YES -ro -al -so "GEOJSON:/vsicurl/https://www.example.com/geojson-endpoint"

This seemed to work better, but yielded the following error:
ERROR 1: Range downloading not supported by this server!

I guess that GDALs vsicurl driver always uses range requests, and these are not supported by Cloudfront, as suspected.
